# heroku rake db:migrate aborting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

```
heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- acts_as_ferret

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
(in /disk1/home/slugs/310513_b4b7e61_4c01/mnt)
```

It show this message issue. how do I fixes this?

Comment: can you provide some more details please?  does you app use ferret?  do you have ferret included in your Gemfile?  Do you have a gitrepo so that others can peruse the code?  a bit more info would help

Comment: Can you provide full trace? so we have more understanding what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. add gem in your gem file "acts_as_ferret"
2. bundle install
3. run heroku run rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Add the gem act_as_ferret gem.

But seems complicated in heroku environement without ferret.